# Which Android devices support multiple Bluetooth Low Energy reading and writing at the same time?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am writing a Android app which allow connecting two BLEs at the same time, then I can send signal to write and read to two BLEs at the same time also. (after some testing) It's working fine for ASUS Memo Pad 7 (4.4.2) and Samsung S4, but not for Moto G (4.4.4) and Nexus 7 which disconnected one and wrote to the other when I tried to write to both at the same time. I don't want to set delay between both devices because I want to signal to both as long as user keep pressing button. That was only four device I tested right now. Did anyone know why it's not working for those devices? is it hardware issue? how do I know which Android devices support to read and write multiple BLE at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to test each device to get this information, no other way.
Ideally on moto G and Nexus 7 it should have worked also. But there are lots of changes in BLE frameworks on **Android 5.1** from Google. I think device supporting 5.1 should allow multiple device read/write operations.